# connection string for aws oracle rds database for nodejs client

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am unable to create connection with oracle rds by aws. My database is public and also open all inbound traffic for oracle instance in aws.

`(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=database.xxx.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))`

The above string working but when i am creating and inserting the table data it shows success but when using select query it gives 0 results.

What i m doing wrong here ?

Comment: that's not a connection issue.  if you are executing inserts without error then the connection is ok.  are you actually committing the DML?

Comment: See: [COMMIT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm)